# Reason for unexpected output in subsetting data frame - R

Tags: r, subset

I have the data frame "a" and it has a variable called "VAL". I want to count the elements where the value of VAL is 23 or 24.

I used two codes which worked Ok:

```
nrow(subset(a,VAL==23|VAL==24) 
nrow(subset(a,VAL %in% c(23,24)))
```

But, I tried other code which gives an unexpected output and I don't know why.

```
nrow(subset(a,VAL ==c(23,24)))
```

Even if I change the order of 23 and 24, it gives a different unexpected output.

```
nrow(subset(a,VAL ==c(24,23)))
```

Why are those codes incorrect ? What are they actually doing?

Comment: You should provide some sample data.

Comment: Thelatmail beat me to an answer but I want to point out that you don't need to use `subset`, rather `nrow(a[a$VAL==23|a$VAL==24])`. Some people prefer `subset` but I've always liked doing things this way.

Comment: @CCurtis, what you suggest is equally inefficient: there is no need to create a whole sub-data.frame then count the number of rows. Instead, just work with a vector: `sum(a$VAL %in% c(23,24), na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: @flodel I never said that was a more efficient method just that it was an alternative. Yes you're right, creating and summing a single vector rather than creating and counting rows in a whole dataframe is faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working through an example shows where it is going wrong:

```
a <- data.frame(VAL=c(1,1,1,23,24))
a
#  VAL
#1   1
#2   1
#3   1
#4  23
#5  24
```

These work:

```
a$VAL %in% c(23,24)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
a$VAL==23 | a$VAL==24
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The following doesn't work due to vector recycling when comparing - take note of the warning message below E.g.:

```
a$VAL ==c(23,24)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#Warning message:
#In a$VAL == c(23, 24) :
#  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

This last bit of code recycles what you are testing against and is basically comparing:

```
c( 1,  1,  1, 23, 24) #to
c(23, 24, 23, 24, 23)
```

...so you don't get any rows returned. Changing the order will give you

```
c( 1,  1,  1, 23, 24) #to
c(24, 23, 24, 23, 24)
```

...and you will get two rows returned (which gives the intended result by pure luck, but it is not appropriate to use).