# subset using a condition in form of vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of **eventId**.
I want to subset a dataset with multiple football events on the basis of this vector.

```
subset(Team1234data, eventId==testvar)
```

where testvar is the vector with eventId and Team1234data is the dataset with many matches and eventId as one of the column.

I am expecting to get the subset of events whose eventid is in the given vector.
But I am getting an error like

```
In eventId == testvar :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: Aren't you looking for something like `testvar %in% eventid`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reason for unexpected output in subsetting data frame - R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145736/reason-for-unexpected-output-in-subsetting-data-frame-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
> Team1234data
  eventID      othercol
1       a other_details
2       b other_details
3       c other_details
> 
> testvar
[1] "a" "c"
> 
> Team1234data[Team1234data$eventID %in% testvar,]
  eventID      othercol
1       a other_details
3       c other_details
> 
>
```

Comment: This is working. If I give 1 input at a time instead of passing a vector it gives the desired results.

Comment: Your comment is not clear. If it is working you should accept the answer.