# An explanation on the behaviour of the "==" operator

Tags: r

In the following very simple example I cannot understand the behavior of the "==" operator.

```
A <- c(10, 20, 10, 10, 20, 30)
B <- c(40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)

df <- data.frame(A, B)

df[df$A == c(10,20), ]      # it returns 3 lines instead of 5
df[df$A %in% c(10,20), ]    # it works properly and returns 5 lines
```

Thank you in advance all of you.

Comment: Very similar to: [Reason for unexpected output in subsetting data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145736/reason-for-unexpected-output-in-subsetting-data-frame-r/23145840)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To understand what is going on you have to understand data frame structure and recycling rules. Data frame is simply a list of vectors.

```
> unclass(df)
$A
[1] 10 20 10 10 20 30

$B
[1] 50 60 50 40 70 80

attr(,"row.names")
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

If you compare two vectors of different length in R the shorter one is [recycled](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule). In your case `df$A == c(10,20)` is equivalent to:

```
> c(10, 20, 10, 10, 20, 30) == c(10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

and

```
> df[c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), ]
   A  B
1 10 50
2 20 60
3 10 50
```

From the [`%in%` documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html):

> `%in%` returns a logical vector indicating if there is a match or not for
>   its left operand

```
> df$A %in% c(10,20)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

and

```
> df[c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), ]
   A  B
1 10 50
2 20 60
3 10 50
4 10 40
5 20 70
```

Comment: I didn't know this about recycling. Thank you zero323.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution that I hope add some insights to other (very good) answers. As stated in "The art of R programming" by Norman Matloff:

> When applying an operation to two vectors that requires them to be the
>   same length, R automatically recycles, or repeats, the shorter one,
>   until it is long enough to match the longer one

if the concept is still not clear. Take a look at this and try to guess the output:

```
c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10) == c(10, 20)
```

which will give:

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

because it recycles the "shorter" vector and by doing so it compares the first `10` on the right to the first on the left (and that's `TRUE`) but compares the second ten with the 20 (the second element of the vector on the right) and that's `FALSE`; after that R recycles the shorter vector (which is the one on the right) and the game starts again.

Comment: And for the readers out there asking how this can possibly be useful? Two example: 1) Grab odd numbered elements from a list vector `vector[c(T, F)]`, grab every 3rd element `vector[c(F,F,T)]` 2) Populate a data.frame/matrix quickly `data.frame(class = "A", values = rnorm(100))`